# Change Color of Lines connecting data points in PGFPlots (LaTeX)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pdftex, color

I have a basic line pgfplot with number of data points. I would like to change the color of line connecting this data points, from Red to Green for last three points. Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
      xlabel=Cost,
      ylabel=Error]
      \addplot[color=red,mark=x] coordinates {
        (2,-2.8559703)
        (3,-3.5301677)
        (4,-4.3050655)
        (5,-5.1413136)
        (6,-6.0322865)
        (7,-6.9675052)
        (8,-7.9377747)
      };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the current output.

[image: basic pgfplot]

And here is what I would like to achieve. (**Note**: Arrows are just to demonstrate the change. Also,   datapoint red (x) color does not matter.)

[image: pgfplot with different line colors]

I have tried to look for the potential solution online, there is a way to change color of line progressively, but I do not want that. Also, I do not want to divide the table into two tables with different colors)
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your custom `colormap` that only consists of the colors you want to use and provide a function such as `ifthenelse(y<=-6,1,0)` to the option `point meta` to tell PGF where to switch the colors. This function will return `1` if the *y* value is below or equal -6, and `0` otherwise.

Then, you can use the shader `flat corner` to disable color mixing, so that every segment of the plot is only in one of the colors provided by your custom colormap.

You may finally want to override the color for the marks using explicit `mark options`:

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        colormap={mycolortable}{
            color=(red) color=(green)
        },
        xlabel=Cost,
        ylabel=Error,
        shader=flat corner,
        point meta={ifthenelse(y<=-6,1,0)},
        mark options={draw=blue}]
        \addplot[mesh, mark=x] coordinates {
            (2,-2.8559703)
            (3,-3.5301677)
            (4,-4.3050655)
            (5,-5.1413136)
            (6,-6.0322865)
            (7,-6.9675052)
            (8,-7.9377747)
        };
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much. Marked as answer.

Comment: Can you also add a conditional that renders the y point if its value is less than -6 but greater than, say, -3?

Comment: @tush There exists no *y* < -6 AND > -3. But you can either nest `ifthenelse()` functions or use the `and()` function or the `&&` or `||` operators. See https://tikz.dev/math-parsing#autosec-7662